# Upload múltiplo de imagens com Fetch API

Tags: php, javascript, async, multiple-file-upload, fetch

Tenho o seguinte código:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" class="selecao_arquivo" id="selecao_arquivo" multiple>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
sendInsucesso.addEventListener('click', e => {
e.preventDefault()
const files = document.querySelector('.selecao_arquivo')
var formData = new FormData(formInsucesso)
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append(files[i].name, files[i])
}
fetch('library/fetch/fetch_form_insucesso.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new URLSearchParams(formData)
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error => console.error(error))
```

})

Consigo **enviar** para o **PHP** porém, recebo os dados dos arquivos como **[object File]**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: formData.append(files[i].name, files[i].files[0]), tenta isso

Comment: @RogerioSantos valeu pela dica, porém continuo com o mesmo problema irmão, tô buscando outras soluções, mas tá dificil!

Answer (score 0):

Na realidade,

```
const files = document.querySelector('.selecao_arquivo')
```

esta constante *não* é uma array, embora seja do tipo Iterable, essa constante é na verdade uma [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList).
Sendo assim, `files[i]` nao retorna o que tu realmente queres.

tenta trocar

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append(files[i].name, files[i])
}
```

para

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files.item(i);
    const filename = file.name;
    formData.append(filename, file)
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, porém continuo com o mesmo problema! 'image' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '[object File]' (length=13)...